# How to set background-image to ::before selector in code behind C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Currently I was trying to use [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)code to set background image to `div` but it was unsuccessful when I try to put the background image into `div` and use the `div` id to set the style to `:before`.

Here is my code:

CSS code:

```
#theme1:before {

   width: 106px;
   content: " ";
   position: absolute;
   left: -16px;
   top: -6px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

ASPX code:

```
<div id="theme1" runat="server">
     <div id="theme2" runat="server">
         hello <br/>
     </div>
</div>
```

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    theme1.Style["background-image"] = "Pic/img.jpg";
    theme2.Style["background-image"] = "Pic/img1.png";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using attributes.add instead of style eg.

theme1.attributes.add('style', 'background-image(image path)')

That should work

Comment: Your code just add inline styles to an element. Example: `<div id="theme1" style="background-image(image path)"></div>`.